# Changing the elements of double array

Tags: python, arrays

I created array like this,

```
matrix = [[".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."],
      [".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".",".","."]]

print('\n'.join([' '.join([str(cell) for cell in row]) for row in matrix]))
```

I want to changing element of array. For example, when user enter input like 0 2, i wanted to change the matrix[0][2] with " | " how can i do that? I know how can i get input i am just  curious about replacing  part.

Comment: You can read the following https://realpython.com/lessons/indexing-and-slicing/

Comment: change the word "with" in your question to `=` and put that in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet:

```
def change(matrix, i, j, element):
    matrix[i][j] = element
    return matrix
```

You don't need a function to do this!

Comment: A function is unnecessary and the input isn't the new matrix value.

Comment: Of course, it is learning not production the need here. So it is just a usable block that I provide...

Comment: It isn't usable though, it doesn't do what the op is asking.